# How to use CSS to adjust HTML5 validation indicator

Tags: css, html

On my HTML5 input fields I am using `required` and CSS to display asterix and other indicators to tell the user their input is valid.
For one of my input fields the `type="number"` which puts arrows to adjust the value up and down by `1`. Unfortuantely these arrows are covering the indicators. I have been trying to use CSS to adjust the placement of these indicators and what I thought was going to be a simple task is not.
I can easily adjust all positions for the general case but not for one targeted case.

[image: example of problem]

HTML

```
<li>
   <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
   <input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity" required />
<li>
```

CSS

```
.contact_form input:required, .contact_form textarea:required {
    background: #fff url(../image/product/none/red_asterisk.png) no-repeat 98% center;
}

.contact_form .quantity input:required {
    background: #fff url(../image/product/none/red_asterisk.png) no-repeat 92% center;
}
```

Comment: Some grammar mistakes make it difficult for me to understand what you're asking for. Please re-read, correct and clarify your question.

Comment: apologies, long day. I hope this clears up my problem. I mention HTML5 only to show where I am using it. i.e. with `required`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the input type number this way:

```
.contact_form input[type="number"]:required
```

And then adjust the asterix position.

```
.contact_form input[type="number"]:required {
    background: #fff url(../image/product/none/red_asterisk.png) no-repeat 96% center;
}
```